# why cant I configure redirected port for an xps driver

Tags: windows, port, driver, printers, redmon

I have Redmon 1.9 installed. I am trying to configure an XPS based printer driver to a Redirected Port but I get the following error:
[image]

But it is working fine for other Unidrv and Postscript based drivers.

How can I add a redirected port for an XPS driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because Unidrv and Pscript are GDI based and XPSdrv is not.